# Is there a way to monitor the quality of healthcare and dental care I am receiving?

Tags: mental-health, oral-health, health-informatics, qualifiy-certify, second-opinion

It could be a particular online website for reviews, a list of doctor's strength and weaknesses during some kind of an assessment, and or anything that can give consumers a greater capacity in gauging the quality of the work their doctors have done on them.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

Quality can be monitored by clinical decision support (CDS) modules. Most CDS logic is implemented inside a software used by clinicians. Patient facing CDS is included in some personal heatlh record (PHR) platforms. (e.g., reminders to get vaccination).
See https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25243350

So you might try to have a computer logic check your past health record and provide reminders and generated comments. (a machine-based second opinion) but not super comprehensive. But in  future, more patient facing CDS is coming.

For dental care, there is much fewer CDS modules.

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. We work differently than most SE sites in that we have a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) so that the answer can be independently verified regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help] or [meta]. Unreferenced claims can lead to answers being deleted.

Comment: reference added. For some answers expert opinion is needed. Than you might just as well close this SE subsite and switch to wikipedia.

Comment: This issue has been thoroughly discussed and agreed upon by the community in meta. You're free to join the discussion there and offer your opinion. You might also want to read what's already been discussed to learn the reasoning behind the rule.